# Reputation for the answer when the questions get merged

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10594/converting-arbitrary-distribution-to-uniform-one) was cross-posted on math.SE. It got separate answers there and here (by me), both of them were accepted. After the merge, the one from the math.SE is shown to be accepted, but I still get 15 reputation from my answer. This is consistent with `/reputation` page:

```
 2     10560 (10)
 2     10560 (10)
 2     10560 (10)
 2     10560 (10)
 2     10593 (10)
 1     10593 (15)
 2     10593 (10)
-- 2011-05-10 rep +75   = 6425
```

I think it is a bug, i.e. I should have lost the 15 reputation points after the merge. Please fix it :)